# Why can I not output the output of range() to a file?

Tags: python, file-io

```
for x in range(6):
  why = str(x+1)
  outf.write(why)
```

where outf is a file

gives me:

```
why = str(x+1)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Comment: It appears you are dying on the call to `str()`, not the file write.  Could you provide a larger, otherwise working example of your problem?

Comment: Are you sure the code you've shown is actually the code you're running?

Comment: Have you bound the name `str` to something else previously?

Comment: An easy way to check what @wim has said is at the point it barfs - `import __builtin__; print str is __builtin__.str`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced you've posted the code you're running, but there are other ways of writing it that avoid explicit calling of `str` and +1'ing (assuming one number per line is intended and 2.x):

```
for i in xrange(1, 7): # save the +1
    print >> fout, i 

fout.writelines('{}\n'.format(i) for i in xrange(1, 7))

from itertools import islice, count
fout.writelines('{}\n'.format(i) for i in islice(count(1), 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (in ipython, python 2.7 ):

```
In [1]: outf = open('/tmp/t', 'w')

In [2]: for x in range(6):
   ...:     why = str(x+1)
   ...:     outf.write(why)

In [3]: outf.close()
```

The content of the file: 123456

What python version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
outf = open('/temp/workfile', 'w')
for x in range(6):
    why = str(x+1)
    outf.write(why)
outf.flush()
outf.close()
```

`/temp/workfile` contains `123456`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are new to Python...

```
new_File = open('mynewfile.txt', 'wr')
for x in range(6):
    new_File.write(str(x)+'\n')

new_File.close()
```

Will give you output to a file called "mynewfile.txt" that looks like:

```
0 
1 
2
3
4
5
```

As far as your pasted code goes, there is something else you arne't telling us... this works just fine.

```
for x in range(6):
  why = str(x+1)
  print why

1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: Context managers are also a good habit to build early on:  `with open('newfile.txt','w') as fout:` ...